# Spark not working with worker in other machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run spark with master on one machine and worker on another. But when trying to read a base with spark (connected to master) I get the following error:

```
23/03/03 07:03:34 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 7897120867509670352
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMessages$RegisterBlockManager; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -699032251763294541, local class serialVersionUID = -5464070606352341135
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:560)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2020)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$deserialize$2(NettyRpcEnv.scala:299)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$deserialize$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:298)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:109)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
23/03/03 07:03:34 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost an executor 0 (already removed): Unable to create executor due to Exception thrown in awaitResult:
```

I'm using a docker container on each of the machines to ensure that all packages are in the same version and even so the reported error happens.

I've run it with and without a docker container and the problem persists. Docker's network configuration is host.

Comment: This looks like you might have incompatible versions of libraries. Have you created the images of those containers yourself? Or manually added some dependencies?

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP and I did update the images myself to get rid of warnings by adding some *.properties files. Other things are added during the execution of a spark job: org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1 and io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0. The aws package version matches the spark version to prevent an error about org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found.

Comment: Oops... @Koedlt, you were right. It was a version issue. Throughout my experiments the spark version was upgraded to 3.3.2, so needed to update the hadoop-aws version too.

Comment: Nice that you found it @BlueIced!